# JaCoCo Coverage not Calculated Correctly

Tags: junit, jacoco

I've a pretty standard Java-Maven build with some plain JUnit tests and some for Arquillian. JaCoCo is hooked via Maven like this:

```xml
    <properties>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    </properties>

<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
            <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Running Sonar now seems to work, however the code coverage is all wrong. I'm not sure if these are separate issues or if there is one problem with the configuration producing all of them, so I'll just list them:

- test suites are not run at all (meaning JUnit tests with `@RunWith(AllTests.class)`)
- Arquillian tests (with `@RunWith(Arquillian.class)`) are run, but the code coverage is wrong, i.e. entities have a code coverage of 0%
- an entire module is not tested and I'm not sure why (all but one of the tests has `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`, but this annotation works in another module)

(After [Qword](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4533347/qword)'s suggestion I tried it without the `reportPath`. However the reports in *target/sites/jacoco/* are still missing the coverage.)

I'm wondering if the problem is with the JUnit runners or maybe because some of these tests are in another module than the classes they test (Arquillian / integration tests especially). On the other hand, some of the JUnit runners seem to work as well. Maybe it's a third component that breaks the build.

I tried [arquillian-extension-jacoco](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-jacoco) as well, this plug-in doesn't seem to work at all (tests won't even start).

Is the problem with the JUnit runners? With the integration tests? How do I fix this?

Answer (score -2):

You don't actually need to specify `sonar.jacoco.reportPath`. First of all, it's been deprecated in favor of `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths`. Second, if you specify the latter property, all reports will be created in a single binary file, but this is not default Jacoco behaviour (and SonarQube [deprecated that as well](https://jira.sonarsource.com/projects/MMF/issues/MMF-1651?filter=allissues)).

I would suggest, as a first step, to

- Entirely remove properties `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` and `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths`
- Remove the `configuration` node from Jacoco plugin definition

Now, you'll won't find anymore the `jacoco.exec` file but instead for every module you'll find a new directory `target/sites/jacoco` in which there will be reports in CSV, XLM, and HTML. This is the standard Jacoco behaviour in v0.8.4.

I'm not entirely sure this will fix **all** your problems, but at least

- I'm quite sure SonarQube will be able to correctly pick up the reports and show the coverage
- You'll be able to analyse coverage with a simple `mvn clean install` on your local machine without having to go to SonarQube every time

Comment: This fixes *none* of my problems. The reports in _target/sites/jacoco/_ are missing the coverage, too. Although now I'm beginning to think this might be due to the fact that the tests are in a different module than the classes to be tested. Although that is a standard use case and works even in Tycho.